# Cannot access a property of a newly filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, typeerror

[Click here for console output!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5mJO.png)

I'm trying to access the property 'allergies' of a newly filtered array but it throws an error 'can't read property of undefined'. Here's my code:

```
   let activePatients = patients.filter(patient => patient.mealPlans.length > 0);
console.log(activePatients); //this appears in the console!
console.log(activePatients[0]);  //this too!
console.log(activePatients[0].allergies); //this throws the following error
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'allergies' of undefined

However, when I write `'typeOf(activePatients[0])'` it logs Object.

This is what the patients array looks like:

```
0: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
1: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
2: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
3: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
4: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(0), measurements: Array(0), …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And the activePatients array:

```
0: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
1: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
2: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
3: {favoriteFoods: Array(0), dislikedFoods: Array(0), allergies: Array(0), mealPlans: Array(1), measurements: Array(0), …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What might be the issue here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you please console.log(patients) before running the code and write the output of it here?

Comment: console.log(activePatients[0])

Comment: My bad, already edited the post! Thanks

Comment: Assuming this isn't Node, could you just screenshot the browser's console? add a `!` before the square brackets to embed the image.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you getting this data asynchronously, like from an http request or database?

Comment: Hey Mark, I fetched the data from the patients array but I can access and manipulate if without trouble. The issue comes at the moment I create a new array (activePatients) which contains only the elements from patients that have certain property. Then when I want to access a property of any element of the activePatients array, it throws the error.

Comment: assuming that there were no async calls before this code should work. can you post the code were `patiens` was set?

Comment: It comes from redux. I am guessing that probably the filter is still executing while I try to access the activePatients[0].allergies property